# Phone-gap Login with Facebook get same user id for different user

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried login with facebook in my phonegap application after login successfully get response but in that response i get same user id for different different user.

I tried following code for login with facebook :-

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
    fbLoginSuccess,function (error) { alert("" + error) }
);

 var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
}
```

I get Following response every time for different different Facebook Users.

**login object {"id":"784749268250297","first_name":"XXX","timezone":5.5,"email":"XXX@gmail.com","verified":true,"name":"XXX Jivani","locale":"en_US","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/784749268250297/","last_name":"XXX","gender":"male","updated_time":"2014-09-10T16:28:22+0000"}**

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem after some research.

first need to check loginstatus for user when status connected then need to logout first and then re login using different user then get different user id.

here my code :-

```
facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
         function (status) {
                alert("current status: " + JSON.stringify(status));

                if (status.status == "connected") {

                    facebookConnectPlugin.logout(function(){

                        alert("LOGOUT SUCCESS");

                        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                                fbLoginSuccess,
                                function (error) { alert("" + error) }
                            );


                    },function(){

                        alert("LOGOUT FAIL");

                    }); 


                }
                else{
                     facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                                fbLoginSuccess,
                                function (error) { alert("" + error) }
                     );
                }
         },
         function (e) {
                alert("Failed: " + e);
        });


var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    console.log("UserInfo: "+JSON.stringify(userData));

}
```

Thanks.